# What does the return type 1, -1 and 0 do in a sort function?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Here is the working piece of code given as an answer to the question for implementing sorting of objects and it is working perfectly fine. As I am new to JavaScript I'm not understanding what exactly the return type does. Can anyone explain please?

```
var people= [
     {
        "f_name": "john",
        "l_name": "doe",
        "sequence": "0",
        "title" : "president",
        "url" : "google.com",
        "color" : "333333",
    }
    // etc
];

function sortResults(prop, asc) {
    people = people.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
        else return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
    });
    showResults();
}
```

Argument 'prop' is the propertyName based on which sorting needs to be done, and asc is a boolean type which sorts in asc order if true or desc order if false.

Comment: *"As i am new to jquery i'm not understanding what exactly the return type does."*. It has nothing to do with jQuery. This is pure javacsript basics.  Check `Array.prototype.sort` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Tip: if it doesn't begin with `$(` or `jQuery(`,  it *probably* isn't jQuery.

Comment: @Kobi unless.. `var itsNotJQuery = $.noConflict()` :)

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with JSON. That is an array of objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `Array.sort` and has nothing to do with `jQuery`. Remember that `jQuery` is yet another library developed in javascript.

[**The MDN explains this already:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> If `compareFunction` is supplied, the array elements are sorted
>   according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are
>   two elements being compared, then:
>
> 1. If `compareFunction(a, b)` is less than `0`, sort `a` to a lower index than
>      `b`, i.e. `a` comes first.
> 2. If `compareFunction(a, b)` returns `0`, leave `a` and
>      `b` unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all
>      different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee
>      this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions
>      dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
> 3. If `compareFunction(a, b)`
>      is greater than 0, sort `b` to a lower index than `a`.
> 4. `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of
>      elements `a` and `b` as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are
>      returned then the sort order is `undefined`

It's not mandatory to return only `-1` or `1`.

Comment: @AbhijithKishore glad it was :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it returns how 2 elements should be ordered relative to one another.

If it's -1 then it means that the elements should be swapped because they are in inverse order. So if the

If it's 1 it means that the elements are in the right order.

If it's 0 then it means that the elements are either equal or have equal positions so it doesn't matter in which order they are.